# PHP email not sending to multiple recipients

Tags: php, email

After submitting a PHP form, I want an email to go to multiple recipients, but it does not. It goes to only the first address. It says in the email (in the "To" field that it is sending to the 3 addresses, but it is not. How can I add a CC or BCC to this code (if that is what is needed)? There are question about this on here and I've tried everything I've seen, but nothing is working so far. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
$headers = 'From: CBS Website';
$emailbody = 'Name: '.$_POST['name']."\n"
    .'Company: '.$_POST['company']."\n"
    .'Email: '.$_POST['email']."\n"
    .'Phone: '.$_POST['phone']."\n"
    .'Stage: '.$_POST['stage']."\n"
    .'Budget Range: '.$_POST['budget']."\n"
    .'Geographic Location: '.$_POST['location']."\n"
    .'Permanent: '.$_POST['permanent']."\n"
    .'Semi-permanent: '.$_POST['semi-permanent']."\n"
    .'Special Considerations: '.$_POST['considerations']."\n"
    .'Project Type: '.$_POST['projectType']."\n"
    .'Square Footage: '.$_POST['sqfootage']."\n"
    .'Number of Stories: '.$_POST['stories']."\n"
    .'Schedule: '.$_POST['schedule']."\n"
    .'SF Budget: '.$_POST['sfbudget']."\n"
    .'Future Construction: '.$_POST['futureConst']."\n"
    .'Special Features: '.$_POST['features']."\n"
    .'Restrictions: '.$_POST['restrictions']."\n"
    .'Referral: '.$_POST['referral']."\n";

mail("joedoe@domain.com,janedoe@domain.com,jimmy80@domain.com",'Contact Form Submission', $emailbody, $headers);

echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content=\"0; url=thankyou.php\">";
```

Comment: Really depends on the MTA if multiple addresses are allowed in `To:`, or only in `Cc:`

Comment: The suggestions I've seen are to have a space after the comma or not. I've tried both. Neither work.

Comment: As @mario mentioned try adding Cc: into the headers for other address.

Comment: See the first duplicate. Mailserver logs. Everything else is guessing.